# Using Jupyter Notebook connect to a server graph database with a specified bolt connection

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j

I am trying to make a connection between Jupyter Notebook and a Neo4j server graph. I looked at different methods to achieve this but none of them are working for me. Is giving me the same error.

```
from py2neo import  Graph
graph = Graph(host="neo4j@bolt://63.35.194.218:7687", auth=("neo4j", "neo4j"))
%reload_ext cypher
query= "MATCH (a)-[]-(b) RETURN a.id, b.id limit 1"
data = graph.cypher.execute(query)
data
```

this gives me an attribute error :

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-5bbea41de85c> in <module>
      3 get_ipython().run_line_magic('reload_ext', 'cypher')
      4 query= "MATCH (a)-[]-(b) RETURN a.id, b.id limit 1"
----> 5 data = graph.cypher.execute(query)
      6 data

AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'cypher'
```

I expect to establish a connection between the 2 applications and have returned the id of the nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you are doing a mix between the use of the **cypher extension** of Jupyter, and the use a pure python script (but it's not your main problem)

So you have to make a choice between :

```
pip install py2neo 
from py2neo import Graph
graph = Graph(host="neo4j@bolt://63.35.194.218:7687", auth=("neo4j", "neo4j"))
graph.run("MATCH (a)-[]-(b) RETURN a.id, b.id limit 1").data()
```

In this example I'm using `graph.run` and not `graph.cypher.run`. 
The `graph.cypher.run` has been removed from the version 3 of py2neo.

And

```
pip install ipython-cypher
%load_ext cypher
%cypher MATCH (a)-[]-(b) RETURN a.id, b.id limit 1
```

Comment: thank you for your explanation, everything works now and more important i understand what i did.

Comment: for the second method, can you maybe show me how do I connect to the server graph? i found something like    %%cypher https://me:mypw@myhost:7474/db/data
match (n) return n limit 1

Comment: I tried this but is not working..     %%cypher neo4j@bolt://63.35.194.218:7687/db/data match (n) return n limit 1

Comment: I think that the Cypher extension only use the http endpoint of Neo4j, not the bolt protocol.. SO from what I read from the documentation you should do that : `%%cypher http://neo4j:neo4j@63.35.194.218:7474/db/data match (n) return n limit 1`

Comment: the syntax is correct but I get another error UsageError: Line magic function `%%cypher` not found.

Comment: I would like to use the other connection because I will need to parametrize some queries and I already found how to do it.